# NewSQL databases that integrate with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, nuodb

Are there any NewSQL offerings out there that integrate with Entity Framework? The only one I know of is NuoDB. Just wondering if there are others.

Answer (score 4):

More info re: NuoDB: Our latest release, 2.0.4, has an updated .NET driver which now supports Entity Framework 6 and for extension installs on Visual Studio 2013.

More info here: http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/Release+Notes

Hope this helps.

Steve Cellini - NuoDB product manager